# Error: "no member named 'uint8_t' in the global namespace" on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

```
Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2:build louisduplessis$ cmake .. && make
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:203:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:158:8: error: no
      member named 'uint8_t' in the global namespace
using::uint8_t;
     ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:159:8: error: no
      member named 'uint16_t' in the global namespace
using::uint16_t;
     ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:160:8: error: no
      member named 'uint32_t' in the global namespace
using::uint32_t;
     ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:161:8: error: no
      member named 'uint64_t' in the global namespace
using::uint64_t;
     ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:178:8: error: no
      member named 'uint_fast8_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_fast8_t;
     ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:179:8: error: no
      member named 'uint_fast16_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_fast16_t;
     ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:180:8: error: no
      member named 'uint_fast32_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_fast32_t;
     ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/path_planning.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/path_planning.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix these fatal errors?
I installed cmake using brew, and these errors started appearing when I upgraded to a new Mac.

Does this have something to do with the preferences in cmake itself?

Comment: I posted another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211717/8203711) From what I've been seeing in different places this is one of many problems for developers caused by the Mojave update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the same error in **npm install hummus** or when I try **clang++ test.cpp** for

```
      #include <cstdint>

      int main(int argc, char **argv) {
         return 0;
      }
```

To compile, add the Mac SDK to the include paths:

**clang++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk test.cpp**