# SCTK installation: no member named uint16_t in the global namespace

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am trying to install the SCTK from NIST found here: https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools

I ran a `make all` command and got errors about types of ints not being members in the global namespace. (`uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, and some others)

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:159:8: error: no
      member named 'uint16_t' in the global namespace
using::uint16_t;
     ~~^
```

I am not sure why I am getting these errors, any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am using:

- MAC OS X 10.13.6 (High Sierra)
- g++ "Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)"

**--- AFTER INSTALLING XCODE ---**

I installed XCode, after looking at [Error: "no member named 'uint8_t' in the global namespace" on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590038/error-no-member-named-uint8-t-in-the-global-namespace-on-macos), but now I am getting pretty much the same errors as above, except that the path is different:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdint:159:8: error: 
  no member named 'uint16_t' in the global namespace
using::uint16_t;
     ~~^
```

Comment: Need to tell us your OS, compiler and their versions.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I added the OS and compiler versions in my post

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590038/error-no-member-named-uint8-t-in-the-global-namespace-on-macos?

Comment: Maybe... I am installing XCode now. Do I need XCode for this to work?